# Is camera magnification a constant?

Tags: image-processing, camera

Magnification $M$ is defined as $\frac{-d_i}{d_o}$, where $d_i$ and $d_o$ denote the image distance and object distance, respectively. For a given camera, is the value $M$ typically the same for all values of $d_o$? That is, is it true that $\frac{d_{i_1}}{d_{o_1}} = \frac{d_{i_2}}{d_{o_2}}$ for all $d_{o_1}, d_{o_2}$ where $d_{i_1}$ and $d_{i_2}$ are the corresponding image distances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes for a given camera with a fixed focus lens, sensor size and sensor to lens distance the optical magnification;
$$ M = |{ \frac{ h_{obj} }{h_{img} } }|$$ 
which is object vertical length divided by its image length on the sensor (a number less than unity, hence a reduction,  unless a **macro** image is taken with  a macro lens wihich has a true magnification) will be a **constant** for most of the proper object distance range.

Comment: But, given an image and a magnification value, is there a way to work out $h_{img}$? Can pixels in an image be converted to physical height in mm?

Comment: yes of course you have to convert pixel size to real world size.

Comment: But isn't the pixel to mm conversion dependent on the resolution of the display? Can the conversion be done programmatically?

Comment: yes and yes. You have a sensor **size** and total number of pixels (resolution) from which you find the conversion **scale factor** as $s_f$  mm/pixel